# ¿Existe un Intent de Play Store que se lance cuando se instala una app?

Tags: java, android

Quiero saber si existe algún **Intent** que **Play Store** accione cada vez que se instala correctamente una aplicación, he visto que existe una llamada `INSTALL_REFER` pero esta es para campañas y analytics, basicamente lo que busco es saber cada vez que el usuario **instale** una app desde la Play Store o desde cualquier otro método, estoy programando un **launcher** y quiero poder realizar algunas acciones cuando una app se instale.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

El usuario puede instalar la aplicación, pero el punto que determina su uso es cuando abre la aplicación, como opción puedes almacenar en una preferencia un valor booleano el cual indicará la aplicación ya fue iniciada por primera ocasión.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(!prefs.getBoolean("iniciaAplicacion", false)) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("iniciaAplicacion", true);
    editor.commit();


   //*** realiza acción al iniciar por primera ocasión la aplicación.

}
```

Comment: creo que no me di a entender bien, lo que quiero es que mi aplicación una vez instalada, pueda detectar la instalación de cualquier otra app y si Android dispara algún Intent cada vez que una app es instalada para notificar al sistema